random one_to_one chat using flask
I am trying to build a flask app in which users can choose a pseudo and chat in one_to_one chat randomly with skip option , the problem here is that when user choose his username and redirect him to waiting page , it still stuck in there even when i open the website in an other browser (trying it on localhost and working on pychram)
ps : i'm a beginner
(https://i.sstatic.net/MBnK1UGp.png)
import random
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session, send_from_directory
from datetime import datetime
import os
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'uploads'
os.makedirs(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], exist_ok=True)

socketio = SocketIO(app)

messages = []
users = []
pairs = {}

@app.route('/')
def choose_username():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/set_username', methods=['POST'])
def set_username():
    username = request.form['name']
    session['username'] = username
    users.append(username)
    session['paired'] = False
    return redirect(url_for('chatroom'))

@app.route('/chatroom')
def chatroom():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('choose_username'))
    return render_template('chat_room.html', messages=messages, username=session['username'], paired=session['paired'])

@app.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
def logout():
    username = session.get('username')
    if username in users:
        users.remove(username)
    if username in pairs:
        partner = pairs.pop(username, None)
        if partner:
            pairs.pop(partner, None)
            clear_messages(username, partner)
    session.pop('username', None)
    socketio.emit('update_users', users, broadcast=True)
    return redirect(url_for('choose_username'))

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    username = session.get('username')
    if username:
        join_room(username)
        socketio.emit('update_users', users, broadcast=True)
        pair_user()  # Attempt to pair the user upon connection

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
    username = session.get('username')
    if username in users:
        users.remove(username)
    if username in pairs:
        partner = pairs.pop(username, None)
        if partner:
            pairs.pop(partner, None)
            clear_messages(username, partner)
    socketio.emit('update_users', users, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on('send_message')
def handle_send_message(data):
    if 'username' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('choose_username'))

    name = session['username']
    message_text = data['message']
    timestamp = datetime.now()
    file_path = None

    if 'file' in data:
        file = data['file']
        filename = f"{timestamp.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}_{file['filename']}"
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(file['data'])
        file_path = os.path.join('uploads', filename)

    new_message = {'name': name, 'message': message_text, 'timestamp': timestamp.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), 'file_path': file_path}
    messages.append(new_message)
    emit('new_message', new_message, broadcast=True)

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)

@socketio.on('check_pairing')
def handle_check_pairing():
    username = session.get('username')
    paired = session.get('paired', False)
    emit('pairing_status', {'paired': paired})

@socketio.on('skip')
def handle_skip():
    username = session.get('username')
    if username in pairs:
        partner = pairs.pop(username, None)
        if partner:
            pairs.pop(partner, None)
            clear_messages(username, partner)
    session['paired'] = False
    pair_user()  # Pair the skipping user with another random user

def pair_user():
    global pairs
    available_users = [user for user in users if user not in pairs]
    if len(available_users) >= 2:
        user1 = random.choice(available_users)
        available_users.remove(user1)
        user2 = random.choice(available_users)
        pairs[user1] = user2
        pairs[user2] = user1
        socketio.emit('pairing', {'user1': user1, 'user2': user2}, room=user1)
        socketio.emit('pairing', {'user1': user1, 'user2': user2}, room=user2)
        socketio.emit('update_pairs', pairs, broadcast=True)
        for user in (user1, user2):
            if 'username' in session and session['username'] == user:
                session['paired'] = True

def clear_messages(user1, user2):
    global messages
    messages = [m for m in messages if m['name'] not in (user1, user2)]
    socketio.emit('clear_messages', {'user1': user1, 'user2': user2}, room=user1)
    socketio.emit('clear_messages', {'user1': user1, 'user2': user2}, room=user2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True)



Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
